# WatiN need to declare browser outside of STAThreaded thread

Tags: c#, watin

I'm currently trying to use WatiN to do some automatic data collection. I used to use a WebBrowser controll, and the way I did it was I declared a stathread and ran it from there, then using a Browser.DocumentCompleted I started a `void LoginPageLoaded` on which I would set the user and pass, and login. Thing is, with WatiN, I'm trying to do

```
var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
    Browser browser = new IE(url);
    browser.WaitForComplete();
    HolyThunder hl = new HolyThunder();
    l.LoginPageLoaded();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
```

But obviously, when I try to use the browser instance on the LoginPageLoaded void it says it downs't know what it is, because it was declared inside the th thread. I didn't do it when I ran LoginPageLoaded through `browser.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(LoginPageLoaded);`, and I obviously can't declare the browser outside of that STAThread. What do you think I can do to fix this?

EDIT - I failed so bad... if I do everything I need to do inside that STAthread, everything will work. My question now is, in watin, is there anyway to open a "webbrowser" without actually having the visual component of the webbrowser?

Comment: It's a bad idea to edit a question into a totally different question, particularly if there are already answers to the old question.  First, it removes context from answers.  Second, you lose the history of the old question via searching.  Always ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using NHtmlUnit, it's a headless browser. I am not sure if you can do it with WatiN.

Answer (score 0):

You can run WebKit headless (see, for example http://phantomjs.org/), but I don't know if you can drive it from WatiN.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how I could, for example, log in to a webpage usinc phantomjs from my c# application? I'm just learning c#.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to hide web browser window.
In that case try this:

```
Settings.Instance.MakeNewIeInstanceVisible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

To  open a "webbrowser" without actually having the visual component of the webbrowser, use

```
var browser = new IE();
browser.Visible = false;
```